# Angular JS scope issue module not reading controller scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a project i am using Angular 1.0.8. I created the project setup my routes properly and my controllers and when I try access the $scope in my routes it gives me a problem, I have to go and access the scope vars that I set by using **$scope.$$prevSibling[variables]** did I set up something wrong?? I created a similar project with the same structure and it works fine I can access the $scope directly using my module?

```
function AppCtrl($scope) {
$scope.navigation = [

 { name: "main", route: "#/" },
 { name: "edit", route: "#/edit" },
 { name: "save", route: "#/save" },
 { name: "settings", route: "#/settings" }

];

$scope.currentPage = null;

$scope.setCurrentPage = function (index) {

    $scope.currentPage = $scope.navigation[index];

}

angular.forEach($scope.navigation, function (value, key) {

    $scope[value.name + "Active"] = "";

})

$scope.setActive = function (name) {

    angular.forEach($scope.navigation, function (value, key) {

        $scope[value.name + "Active"] = "";

    })

    $scope[name + "Active"] = "active";

}

}
```

Here is my module setup:

```
angular.module('Sample', [])
       .config(appRouter);

function appRouter($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl: "partials/default.html",
        controller: function ($scope) {

            console.log($scope.$$prevSibling.setActive);

        }
    })
 }

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Sample">
<head>
   <title>Sample Angular App</title>
   <script src="Scripts/lib/basket.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
   <script src="Scripts/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/controllers/app.js"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="wrapper" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
       <div class="navigation">
          <ul class="cf">
             <li ng-repeat="link in navigation" ng-class="{active:$index == activeIndex}" class="{{link.name}}"><a class="icon-{{link.icon}}" href="{{link.route}}"> {{link.name | uppercase}} </a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="viewWrapper">
           <div class="sidebarParent">
              <div ng-include src="sidebarUrl" class="sidebar">

              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="viewParent">
               <div ng-view class="view">

                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
   </html>
```

style.css is for my icon fonts, global.css is for my main style, basketjs is store some scripts locally so I can work with easeljs later, the ng-repeat is there to build the navigation. Everything is working but its just that the scope is off?? I have to go to the prevSibling? controllers/app.js is where AppCtrl is located, and Scripts/app.js is where my module is located.

Comment: Where are you using `AppCtrl`? Can we see the HTML code for `partials/default.html`?

Comment: I have an index html file and the module and controller are both being called from the same index page.

Comment: The partials are working the ajax requests are loading those pages properly, Maybe it would be better if I create a jsbin for it. but I am not sure if the problem would be replicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying a little more about angular I realized that $$prevSibling goes up the scope chain of the elements so if you don't have an element to go to in the next scope level then you are going to receive back a null object because there is nothing there.